# React build not working whereas working fine when I start the server locally

Tags: reactjs, build, create-react-app

I have a React project which runs fine when I do `npm run start`. All the elements load completely fine.

But when I create a build using `npm run build`, the resulting build when run would not load the elements.

In my package.json I have homepage also set like this:

```
"homepage": ".",
```

Also, there are no errors in console.

During compile time as well there are no warnings.

Any suggestions on what could I be missing or some steps I must try to find what could be going wrong?

I tried deleting the node_modules, clearing node cache and rebuilding but that too did not help

Thank you!

Comment: how do you run build files?

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh - I am hosting the build files on a server so the index.html would run by default

Comment: if you run build files locally, will see same result ?

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh yes, getting the same results

But if I start the server locally using `npm run start` all the elements load fine. After the build the elements would not load

Comment: could you please tell me the command that you run build files locally?

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh I use `npm run build`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249662/discussion-between-dhruvin-and-ali-sattarzadeh).